# Changing data diagonally in matrix based on formula and table

Tags: matlab

Let says I have this matrix:

```
                        (x)
 X = [1     1     1     0     1     0     0     0;
      1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0;
      1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0;
      0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1;
      1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0;
      0     1     0     0     1     1     0     1;
      0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1;
      0     0     0     1     0     1     1     1];
```

and this table:

```
        kzz   
      _______

1        80
2        80
3        23
4        14
5        63
6        36 
7        41     
8         5
```

and this equation:

```
 f = (1/visc)*((2*kzz2*kzz1*az2*az1)/(kzz2*az2*delz+kzz1*az1*delz)

visc = 2
az2 = 6400
az1 = 6400
delz = 30
kzz1 = ? < From the table
kzz2 = ? < From the table

 f = (1/2)*((2*kzz2*kzz1*6400*6400)/(kzz2*6400*30+kzz1*6400*30)
```

this equation represent the diagonal started from column 5 in the matrix, just below the (X).

---

The required task is: changing the ones in this diagonal to this equation:

```
f = (1/2)*((2*kzz2*kzz1*6400*6400)/(kzz2*6400*30+kzz1*6400*30)
```

For the first value in the diagonal " Matrix(5,1) "
kzz2 = 63 and kzz1 = 80 << which obtained from the table

therefore, the equation will be as follow:

```
f = (1/2)*((2*63*80*6400*6400)/(63*6400*30+80*6400*30)
```

so based on the location on matrix, the code should take the value from the table and substitute it in the equation.

My trial is:

```
k = (4);
d = diag(Matrix,k); 
n = d;
n(n==1) = f; 
XX = XX - diag(d,k) + diag(n,k);
```

## Example of required output

the output should look like this (imaginary numbers)

```
 1     1     1     0     5     0     0     0
 1     1     0     1     0     8     0     0
 1     0     1     1     0     0     9     0
 0     1     1     1     0     0     0     2
 1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
 0     1     0     0     1     1     0     1
 0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     1     0     1     1     1
```

other equations will be used to change the other diagonals to get this result:

```
 1     2     1     0     5     0     0     0
 1     1     0     1     0     8     0     0
 1     0     1     6     0     0     9     0
 0     1     1     1     0     0     0     2
 1     0     0     0     1     7     1     0
 0     1     0     0     1     1     0     1
 0     0     1     0     1     0     1     4
 0     0     0     1     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. If other variables such as `kxx` and `kyy` are unrelated to the question please edit the question and remove them and provide a minimum example with the expected output.

Comment: the question is edited, I hope its clear now, thanks for your kind advise, I'm new to the website, and sorry for any ambiguities

Comment: Unfortunately I can't realize  what you are trying to do. Explaining,step by step,  how the output can be computed from input is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. If the az1,az2,delz,visc are constants and kzz1=kzz(rowIndex), kzz2=kzz(columnIndex) as it seems to be the case from your example, this seems to be ok for what you are trying to do.

```
az1 = 6400;
az2 = 6400;
delz = 30;
visc = 2;

i=0;
for j=5:8
    i=i+1;
    X(i,j) = (1/visc)*(2*kzz(j)*kzz(i)*az2*az1)/(kzz(j)*az2*delz+kzz(i)*az1*delz);
end
```

If you want to generalize for a diagonal starting at the `startColumnIndex`, the for loop can be something like that:

```
i=0;
startColumnIndex = 5;
numberOfColumns = size(X,2);
for j = startColumnIndex : numberOfColumns
    i=i+1;
    .....stuff you want to do......
end
```

Comment: @user11234070 I did an edit to your question to try and clarify what it was you were asking exactly.